# Django not loading images from CSS file

Tags: python, css, django, django-staticfiles

I have my HTML file which links to the CSS and it is working fine

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/Website/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/Website/css/style.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/Website/css/ionicons.min.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/Website/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" />e here
```

Then I have several images in the HTML file which are loading fine

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static '/Website/images/fav.png' %}"/>
```

One div element id `<div id="lp-register">` obviously links to above style.css selector as per below

```
#lp-register{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0, 0.7) , rgba(0,0,0, 0)), url('../images/test.png') fixed no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

the images are in the static folder structured as this

```
static 
   - images 
       - test.png
```

and the setting.py has the correct static file definition

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

When I load the HTML page that particular image is not being loaded, and no error I see in the Django server, furthermore if I inspect the element I see that `url('../images/test.png')` remain with the old settings

```
linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0, 0.7) , rgba(0,0,0, 0.7)), url("http://placehold.it/1920x1280") fixed no-repeat
```

and does not change no matter what. In addition to that if I inspect the element and modify the settings manually to

```
 linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0, 0.7) , rgba(0,0,0, 0)), url('../images/test.png') fixed no-repeat
```

which is what I want, seems that is working fine but when I change it in CSS does not

Can anybody help please?

Comment: I don't see `Website` anywhere in folder structure or settings. Try removing this url part.

Comment: that folder structure is only for the static files Website is above Static and is working fine everywhere apart from the css file that needs to load that test.png file

Comment: So real folder structure is `static/Website/static/images`, right?

Comment: No no the real structure is NameProject/static/website/images for the images for css is NameProject/static/website/css . css works but loading the images defined in the css file does not

Comment: By the way do you mean dev or prod server, DEBUG=true or false?

Comment: I found the problem, thanks for your help. I did not realize that style.css and img where in the same folder and when referencing the images the path was wrong

Answer (score 0):

`{% load static%}` in your HTML and then load the stylesheet.
You have set the static files in the settings.py the correct way, I think this should work.

`url('../images/test.png')` for this kind of linking in CSS we have to use this way to call these static files

`url('{% static 'images/test.png' %}')`